# Locking strategies and techniques for preventing deadlocks in code

Tags: c++, design-patterns, locking, deadlock

The common solution to preventing deadlock in code is to make sure the sequence of locking occur in a common manner regardless of which thread is accessing the resources.

For example given threads T1 and T2, where T1 accesses resource A and then B and T2 accesses resource B and then A. Locking the resources in the order they are needed causes a dead-lock. The simple solution is to lock A and then lock B, regardless of the order specific thread will use the resources.

Problematic situation:

```
Thread1                         Thread2
-------                         -------
Lock Resource A                 Lock Resource B
 Do Resource A thing...          Do Resource B thing...
Lock Resource B                 Lock Resource A
 Do Resource B thing...          Do Resource A thing...
```

Possible Solution:

```
Thread1                         Thread2
-------                         -------
Lock Resource A                 Lock Resource A
Lock Resource B                 Lock Resource B
 Do Resource A thing...          Do Resource B thing...
 Do Resource B thing...          Do Resource A thing...
```

My question is what other techniques, patterns or common practices are used in coding to guarantee dead lock prevention?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The technique you describe isn't just common: it's the one technique that has been proven to work all the time. There are a few other rules you should follow when coding threaded code in C++, though, among which the most important may be:

- **don't hold a lock when calling a virtual function**: even if at the time you're writing your code you know which function will be called and what it will do, code evolves, and virtual functions are there to be overridden, so ultimately, you *won't* know what it does and whether it will take any other locks, meaning you will lose your guaranteed order of locking
- **watch out for race conditions**: in C++, nothing will tell you when a given piece of data is shared between threads and you don't use some kind of synchronization on it. One example of this was posted in the C++ Lounge on SO chat a few days ago, by Luc, as an example of this (code at the end of this post): just trying to synchronize on something *else* that happens to be in the neighborhood doesn't mean your code is correctly synchronized.
- **try to hide asynchronous behavior**: you're *usually* better hiding your concurrency in your software's architecture, such that most calling code won't care whether there's a thread there or not. It makes the architecture easier to work with - especially for some-one who isn't used to concurrency.

I could go on for a while, but in my experience, the *easiest* way to work with threads is using patterns that are well-known to everyone who might work with the code, such as the producer/consumer pattern: it's easy to explain and you only need one tool (a queue) to allow your threads to communicate with each other. After all, the *only* reason for two threads to be synchronized with each other, is to allow them to communicate.

More general advice:

- Don't try your hand at lock-free programming until you've had experience with concurrent programming using locks - it's an easy way to blow your foot off, or run into very strange bugs.
- Reduce the number of shared variables and the number of times those variables are accessed to a bare minimum.
- Don't count on two events always occurring in the same order, even if you can't see any way of them reversing order.
- More generally: don't count on timing - don't think a given task should always take a given amount of time.

#### The following code will fail:

```
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
 
void
nothing_could_possibly_go_wrong()
{
    int flag = 0;
 
    std::condition_variable cond;
    std::mutex mutex;
    int done = 0;
    typedef std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock;
 
    auto const f = [&]
    {
        if(flag == 0) ++flag;
        lock l(mutex);
        ++done;
        cond.notify_one();
    };
    std::thread threads[2] = {
        std::thread(f),
        std::thread(f)
    };
    threads[0].join();
    threads[1].join();
 
    lock l(mutex);
    cond.wait(l, [done] { return done == 2; });
 
    // surely this can't fail!
    assert( flag == 1 );
}
 
int
main()
{
    for(;;) nothing_could_possibly_go_wrong();
}
```

Comment: "you won't know what it does and whether it will take any other locks" unless the specification of the base-class function is that the method never acquires a lock.

Comment: "that specification would have to be enforced somehow": one might same the same claim about *any* aspect of the specification. In practice hardly any are _enforced_. Some are checked by review, most are checked by testing.

Comment: @Raedwald What I meant to say is that you can't always rely on the specification of a base-class function to reflect the reality of what the function does (and.or other versions of the function do). *most are checked by testing* is correct, and regrettably, that means most problems aren't picked up in time to prevent damage. That doesn't mean the base class function shouldn't be clearly specified - it just means that such specifications, in practice, cannot necessarily be relied upon.

Answer (score 15):

Consistent ordering of locking is pretty much the first and last word when it comes to deadlock avoidance.

There are related techniques, such as lockless programming (where no thread ever waits on a lock, and thus there is no possibility of a cycle), but that's really just a special case of the "avoid inconsistent locking order" rule -- i.e. they avoid inconsistent locking by avoiding all locking.  Unfortunately, lockless programming has its own issues, so it's not a panacea either.

If you want to broaden the scope a bit, there are methods for detecting deadlocks when they do occur (if for some reason you can't design your program to avoid them), and ways for breaking deadlocks when they do occur (e.g. by always locking with a timeout, or by forcing one of the deadlocked threads to have their Lock() command fail, or even just by killing one of the deadlocked threads); but I think they are all pretty inferior to simply making sure deadlocks cannot happen in the first place.

(btw if you want an automated way to check whether your program has potential deadlocks in it, check out valgrind's helgrind tool.  It will monitor your code's locking patterns and notify you of any inconsistencies -- very useful)

Comment: Lock-free programming isn't a technique to avoid inconsistent locking: it's a field of research aimed at creating truly scalable concurrent algorithms. The only issue with lock-free programming is that it is *hard*, so it's not something to recommend to some-one who doesn't have much experience with concurrent programming..

Comment: @rlc and @Jeremy: And "lock-free" programming isn't even really lock free. It's just using locking implemented in the hardware, in the cache coherency protocols and the inter-processor communication. Without some kind of lock the much loved compare-exchange instructions couldn't possibly work.

Comment: @rlc fair enough -- but I didn't claim otherwise, I only said it was a related technique.  @Zan it's lock-free in the sense that a thread is guaranteed not to block indefinitely, and thus there is no chance of a deadlock occurring.

Comment: @ZanLynx true: processors will synchronize with each other and, in the x86 architecture, the LOCK pin is asserted, both of which come at significant cost. The locks themselves are implemented using the same hardware-level synchronization mechanisms, though, and on the *software* level, while there are synchronization points, there are no locks in the sense that at least one thread will always make forward progress. Wikipedia has a nice definition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock-free)

Answer (score 6):

Another technique is transactional programming. This though is not very common as it usually involves specialized hardware (most of it currently only in research institutions).

Each resource keeps track of modifications from different threads. The first thread to commit changes to all resources (it is using) wins all other thread (using those resources) get rolled back to try again with the resources in the new committed state.

A simplistic starting point for reading on the subject is [transactional memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_memory).

Answer (score 3):

While not an alternative to the known-sequence solution you mention, Andrei Alexandrescu wrote about some techniques for compile time checks that acquisition of locks is done through the intended mechanisms.  See http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25298

Answer (score 3):

You are asking about the design level, but I'll add some lower level, programming practices.

- Classify each function (method) as *blocking*, *non-blocking* or having unknown blocking behaviour.
- A *blocking* function is a function that acquires a lock, or calls a slow system call (which in practice means it does I/O), or calls a *blocking* function.
- Whether a function is guaranteed to be non-blocking is part of the specification of that function, just like its preconditions and its degree of exception safety. It must therefore be documented as such. In Java I use an annotation; in C++ documented using Doxygen I'd use a forumalic phrase in the header commentary for the function.
- Consider calling a function that is not *specified* to be non-blocking while holding a lock to be dangerous.
- Refactor such dangerous code to eliminate the danger or to concentrate the danger into a small section of code (perhaps within its own function).
- For the remaining dangerous code, provide an informal proof that the code is not actually dangerous in the commentary of the code.