# DeadLock analysis tool C#

Tags: c#, deadlock

Can somebody help me detect a deadlock in my program using any open source tool?

Comment: If you show us some code we might be able to help you *without* a tool.

Comment: Deadlocks can usually be prevented by applying locking rules: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012640/locking-strategies-and-techniques-for-preventing-deadlocks-in-code

Comment: Firstly, where is this deadlock happening? in your .NET code? in a database transaction? in a WCF transaction? where?

Comment: You should post some code here. It is not clear from your question as to what kind of deadlock are you referring to.

Comment: I'm voting not to close as its a valid question, but PLEASE: give more information.  What are you doing, what's the context, databases, normal threading, file management, etc? It's not answerable like this.

Answer (score 3):

Remember I'm guessing because you didn't provide any code or anything. But, it should be pretty straight forward in Visual Studio. Let's assume your application is running and has hit the deadlock, that would generally mean that multiple threads are stuck on a read/write of a shared variable without using a `lock(...)` operation.

So, if you **pause** debugging in Visual Studio and go to the `Threads` window, you should be able to double-click on each thread and see the line they are paused on, that will at least tell you which entry points are locking. Fixing it will be a much different story because you'll need to figure out how it happened, but this should get you the information you're seeking.

You will likely need to employ locking via the [`lock(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) operation in some context.